# HttpWebReques send Post request as Get

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

With the code below, the request is sent as Get instead of Post, I've set redirects to false with no luck, please assist.

I've updated the question and included more code
string

```
myURI = "https://api.bulksms.com/v1/messages";

string myUsername = "******";
string myPassword = "******";

string myData = "{to: \"7777777777\", body:\"Hello Mr. Mbhele!\"}";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(myURI);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 0;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(myUsername, myPassword);
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "appication/json");
var encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
var encodedData = encoding.GetBytes(myData);

var stream = request.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(encodedData, 0, encodedData.Length);
stream.Close();

try
{
    var response = request.GetResponse();

    var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    return reader;
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred:" + ex.Message);

    var reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream());
    return reader;
}
```

Comment: You appear to have a syntax error in `HttpWebRequest)`.

Comment: What makes you so sure the request is sent as `GET`? How did you test?

Comment: hmm.. it shouldn't matter whether or not you write anything to `RequestStream`.  Please include output of the request and response from those types (like Raw Headers - excluding authentication information) depicting this behavior. also, include your .net framework.

Comment: Please see updated question

Comment: @LuckyMduMsimango, but you still haven't answered Transcendent's question...

Comment: { "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'." }

Comment: I've also checked the request on Fiddler

Comment: @Brett Caswell, version 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similar issue in the future. I was calling the REST API from within another, the post request was getting redirected, changing the first call to [Get] instead of [Post] seems to have done the trick.